# React: Child Components Failed to Receive Multiple Mapped Data Using Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-props, react-component

I'm new to react. I want to create a simple react web app that receives data from 2 api, and display the data.

I have three components. App.js receive data from two api, and pass the data to FruitGrid.js using hooks and props. FruitGrid.js map the two data received, and pass to FruitItem.

My problem is in FruitGrid.js. Data is received in FruitGrid.js, I can see by console log or print using html tags. But when I try to send the mapped data to FruitItem.js by changing the h1 tag to `<FruitItem></FruitItem>`, I can only successfully pass one data, not both of them.

FruitGrid.js

```
import React from 'react';
import FruitItem from './FruitItem';


const FruitGrid = ({ items, images, isLoading }) => { 

    return isLoading ? (
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
    ) : (
        <section>
        {items.map((item) => {
            return <FruitItem key={item.id} item={item}></FruitItem>

        })}

        {images.map(image => {
            return <FruitItem key={image.id} image={image}></FruitItem>
            // return <h1>{image}</h1>
        })}

        </section>
    )    

}

export default FruitGrid;
```

If I only do `return <FruitItem key={item.id} item={item}></FruitItem>` the item data will show in the correct layout, image won't show since I didn't pass. But if I try to pass both item and image using `<FruitItem></FruitItem>`. It will show error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" in FruitItem.

FruitItem.js

```
import React from 'react'

const FruitItem = ({ item, image }) => {

    return (
        <div className='card'>
            <div className='card-inner'>
                <div className='card-front'>
                    <img src={image} alt='' />
                </div>
                <div className='card-back'>
                    <h1>{item.name}</h1>
                    <ul>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    )
}

export default FruitItem
```

Can someone help and let me know how i can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over the two data sources separately, so items are not defined in your `images.map` and images are not defined in your `items.map`

In order to combine, assuming the order of the data is the same/the keys are the same in both cases, you could do something like this:

```
{items.map((item, key) => {
    return <FruitItem key={item.id} item={item} image={images[key]}></FruitItem>
})}
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is what I was looking for! I was searching for how to map two data source together.

Answer (score 1):

Hey @yywhocodes this is happening because the FruitItem.js is always expecting an `item` object and your code for the images mapping is not providing the item object -> `return <FruitItem key={image.id} image={image}></FruitItem>`

What you can do is change the FruitItem.js

from
`<h1>{item.name}</h1>`

to
`{ item ? <h1>{item.name}</h1> : null }`

like that it will try to render the item.name only if the item exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass props `key={item.id} item={item}` to the child FruitItem component. If you can't pass any props to the FruitItem component, react won't figure out the `item.name`. Which will be a TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your FruitItem always expects an item to be handed in

```
<h1>{item.name}</h1>
```

But when you hand in your image, there is no item you set.